# User reputation ranking page is broken

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation-leagues, error-message

Today me and some other users have observed that the reputation ranking page doesn't allow to navigate past page 999.

For example, https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?page=1111&tab=reputation&filter=week shows a page:

> We're sorry... There are an unusual number of requests coming from
> this IP address.
>
> To protect our users, we can't process any more requests from this IP
> address right now.
>
> We'll restore access as quickly as possible, so try again soon.
>
> If you believe you have reached this page in error, contact us.

Comment: Able to reproduce.

Comment: What is the time scale? 10 minutes? 1 hour? 6 hours? Did it only start about 20 minutes ago?

Comment: Seems to apply here in southern UK too... probably not IP related.

Comment: same here, page=999 works, while page=1000 shows mentioned error, also on SO: https://stackoverflow.com/users?page=1000&tab=reputation&filter=week like @Marijn pointed out

Comment: Also reproducible on other sites (I tried TeX.SE).

Comment: @P.Mort.-forgotClayShirky_q 6 hours

Comment: Also on Workplace.  It's easy to reproduce.

Comment: Now solved, can't reproduce.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Your observation is correct. For the past two weeks, we've been hit by an evolving DDoS attack. We noticed the attack before it started affecting the site's performance, and limiting access to user pages beyond the 999th page is one of the mitigation methods we have temporarily put in place. We felt this was the best way to attenuate the attack for now, while we work to create more sophisticated ways to limit DDoS traffic.