# Problem with reputation earned this week

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, reputation, users-page

There is a problem with the [reputation earned so far this week](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users?tab=Reputation&filter=week). For instance, it says that, at the moment that I write, the VP of Community Philippe has earned 1,472 reputation points. That's a little weird, since we are only in the middle of the second day of the week. But [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/936316/philippe?tab=reputation) it can be seen that, in fact, Philippe earned only 220 reputation points so far this week (160 yesterday plus 60 so far today).

The problem can be seen not only here but across the whole Stack Exchange network.

Comment: This is likely related to the outages we experienced on Saturday. I'll see whether there's anything that can be done but it's unclear there will be.

Comment: @Catija speaking of outages - any info on what the heck happened? Another attack? That was quite a downtime

Comment: @Oleg they claim it wasn't DDoS. Maybe other kind of attack (e.g. hacking), we can't know. I can only hope we'll be lucky and SE will decide to share what happened.

Comment: @ARogueAnt. Were you perhaps thinking of this [comment](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377085/periodic-outages-again#comment1257115_377085) which says "Note that the Weekly tab on the Users page (Academia at least) didn't reset rep counts at midnight last night. It is still running last week's total."?

Comment: Oh, that was it, no wonder I couldn't find it. @JohnOmielan I'd been thinking for a while that it'd be handy if comments were searchable.

Comment: Now also reported on MSO: [Reputation league for this week is completely messed up](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/416608/4642212).

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Thanks for the report! The weekly reset route attempted to run but [we were down at the time](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377085/periodic-outages-again). This unfortunately means that, as you noticed, the rep lists for the week are all out of whack.

Since it's just the weekly timeframe, we're leaving them as is and will let them self-correct when the reset route runs next weekend. Some users will also self-correct in the meantime if reputation recalcs happen for other reasons (such as post deletion, user merges, etc), but one way or another, everything should be back in order next Sunday.

Comment: This is a disappointing answer, actually. Is there a search that can give the same information in the short term? And, I suggest finding a permanent solution for the future.

Comment: @Buffy Frankly, if the only thing that could be affected by a DDoS is some people not being able to compare their imaginary internet points for the week, that would be a huge win. I imagine the engineering team have some higher priority tickets right now.

Comment: @Buffy I agree that it's not ideal. And unfortunately there's no search by or for reputation.

Comment: "everything should be back in order next Sunday" - not if the attacker figured this out and will simply send DDoS attacks every Sunday.