# Wrong ranking shown in user page

Tags: bug, users-page, rankings

I just noticed that the ranking shown in the user page seem to be off

[image]

None of the first ranked users did earn that much reputation in the current calendar week.

Comment: Most likely [by-design](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/377132/problem-with-reputation-earned-this-week), sadly. When the mechanism that reset the weekly reputation isn't working, well, it isn't working.

Comment: As it is now, it looks like its going from October 30th to Today (November 8th 2022).  This is based off of summing up the user JBH's reputation on their profile (which is off by 1 by my calculation, presumably because JBH down voted an answer somewhere which isn't displayed on their reputation list).