# Stack Overflow Offline - No announcement

Tags: support, stack-overflow, outage

Stack Overflow is currently offline; it was around half an hour ago too but came back for a short while (but it was showing *very* slow response times).

The "We are currently offline for maintenance" page shows *sometimes* but neither the linked [StackStatus Twitter](https://twitter.com/StackStatus) nor the [Blog](https://stackstatus.net/) has anything about today's outage.

Any news or updates about what's happening, and how long it will likely last?

Comment: This report is status-review: [Some sites are offline, but no blog or Twitter information. Is all OK?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375995/282094) - last time it was a couple of hours. Previous incident: https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/375744/282094

Comment: The other post is about 3 or 4 minutes earlier. But, in my defence, I was going to post some time ago, but the site came back up (the "for a while" I referred to).

Comment: Same here, I was in the bath at the time it all kicked-off. Just the luck of timing that I hit post first.