# How many months in year?

Tags: bug, dates

Just found the [question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/375052/339911) asked 1 year ago, and modified 12 months ago:

> [image]

It looks weird.

Comment: Sign one report too many bugs: they start recycling and reporting same bugs again. (No worry, happened to me as well.)

Comment: @ShadowWizardChasingStars five years ago, still not fixed. Sigh.

Comment: haha, you're still not used to it? They don't fix bugs, I'm not sure why people still bothering to post them, it's like an addiction, knowing it's fruitless. :D